# Dismiss UIAlertView without making it a property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have a `UIAlertView` that I display with no buttons. I'd like to programmatically dismiss it after some action is processed (it is a "Please wait" alert dialog). I'd like to dismiss it, though, without the need for the `UIAlertView` to be a property.

**Why:** Now I am allocating the alert view to a @property - e.g.: I am creating a class variable. I don't feel like it deserves to have it that way - because frankly, it is displayed only when the View Controller is loading. I thought it is somehow added as a subview, that I could pop it from the stack when the loading is done, but that didn't work.

**What:** I create the alert dialog (no buttons) and show it. Then I start processing data - syncing with server. It only happens once and it is not a frequent thing. However, other object takes care of the sync and is implemented as observer pattern - the object itself reports, when the data has been loaded. That's when I dismiss the dialog. I just wanted to avoid using @property for the dialog.

This is how I do it (simplified):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIAlertView *av;

- (void)setup {
       ...
       [self.av show];
       [self loadData];
}

- (void)loadData {
       ...loading data...
       [self.av dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Is there a way how to dismiss it without the need for "storing" it to `@property`?

Comment: can you explain your problem... clearly.. what do you mean by without making it a property..

Comment: Any reason why you want to avoid having that @property? You can probably use [Associated Objects](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/) but honestly, that's worse than a @property.

Comment: I can see the confusion - sorry for lack of clarity. I have edited the question so it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocks retain variables they capture. You can take advantage of that behaviour, but you should understand what you're doing there:

```
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                             message:@"Message"
                                            delegate:nil
                                   cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
[av show];

dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.myqueue", 0), ^{
    sleep(5);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [av dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    });
});
```

The `sleep(5)` is just simulating your long running task.

Instead of using `UIAlertView`, I'd consider using a library like this: https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: I wanted to use this approach but I got stuck on the fact, that the action that would be on the place of `sleep(5)` is now implemented as observer pattern - the change is reported by the other object, it doesn't change by asking.